# Drop down menu using button with image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu using the button with images and I will put some functions on each button, but on the drop-down menu that I use the only button that is available to use is a check button. this is the program that I'm currently using.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mbtn = Menubutton(root, text="Options", relief=RAISED)
mbtn.menu = Menu(mbtn, tearoff = 0)
mbtn["menu"] = mbtn.menu

mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Outing")
mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Sleep")
mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Tour")

mbtn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you call `.grid()` on the `Menubutton` then save that result (which is always `None`) to `mbtn`? Also why are you calling `mbtn.pack()` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve Your issue?

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mbtn = Menubutton(root, text="Options", relief=RAISED)
mbtn.pack()
mbtn.menu = Menu(mbtn, tearoff = 0)
mbtn["menu"] = mbtn.menu

mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Outing")
mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Sleep")
mbtn.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Tour")

root.mainloop()
```

instead of `mbtn.pack()` You can obviously also use `mbtn.grid()` or `mbtn.place()`(not suggested - `.place()`)

@TheLizzard added: You can use `root.config(menu=mbtn.menu)` (instead of `mbtn.pack()`) to make the menu part of the window.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: You can use `root.config(menu=mbtn)` (instead of `mbtn.pack()`) to make the menu part of the window.

Comment: @Matiiss i've tried to use that program as well but Menu does not have attribute for the add_button

Comment: `root.config(menu=mbtn)` should be `root.config(menu=mbtn.menu)` instead.